# ajax call from View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a tool in MVC. When I upload a file I need to take some xls variables out from it and insert them to the Database. This could take 30-40 sec. I would like to  show some feedback to the user while this long process is executed. So I added a function named **GetImportStatus()** which should return the prcessed variables to the user. I add this function to the Controller that executes the insertion in Database. So my controller looks like

```
 public class AdminController : Controller
 {
    int currentIndex;
    int totalVariables;

public ActionResult GetAllVariables()
{
    //processing code here
    totalVariables = Variables.Count;   
}

//other stuffs here

public void InserVariablestToDatabase()
{
    foreach(string variable in VariableList)
    {
        Insert(variable);
        currentIndex++;
    }
}

//other code here

    public JsonResult GetImportStatus()
    {
        return Json((new { Current = currentIndex.ToString(), Total = totalVariables.ToString() }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
}
```

My view has this part,

```
<div id="updateDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateScreen() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetImportStatus","Admin")',
            content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#updateDiv").append("<strong>" + data + "</strong>");
            }
        });
    }

    $("#btnUploadFile").click(function ()
    { var id = setInterval(updateScreen, 1000); });

</script>
```

where "btnUploadFile" is the upload button. When I inspect the .NET panel from firebug, I see the requests but I get no responses until the importing process is finished. See image below 
[image]

Am I doing something wrong? 
Thank You! :)

Comment: have you made debug statement to make sure that call is correct?

Comment: yes, but is not called until the insert operation is finished

Comment: It just a view, could you add in your `ajax` function `async:false,` after `content`

Comment: same thing is happening :(

Comment: I added a breakpoint to the json response and a breakpoint to the last line of the inserting process. The GetImportStatus is called after the Insert process is finished. But I can see the requests from the firebug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as per your scenario you need to have [async methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
private async void InserVariablestToDatabase()
{
     ....
}

public async Task<JsonResult> GetImportStatus()
{
     ....
}
```

You would have worth reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743067/do-asynchronous-operations-in-asp-net-mvc-use-a-thread-from-threadpool-on-net-4).

Comment: It's a little bit embarrassing that for things that look simple you have to do sooo complicated stuffs in the back end. Thanks for your help :)